# Length, width and weight price calculations for silver chains

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I need to add a function to a silver chain website

Require the customer to be able to choose LENGTH - WIDTH - of chain

The base price for 16 inch 1mm chain = $10
I need the price to auto calculate when the customer selects a different option from the drop downs.

Every time the length or weight increases the price will increase too.

When the customer has selected length and width the weight in grams of the chain will show.

For example

```
  Length
  16 inch
  18 inch
  20 inch
```

And

```
  Width
  1mm 
  2mm
  3mm
  4mm
  5mm
```

Comment: Are there a fixed amount of lengths? Does every length/width combination have its own stock keeping code?

Comment: There can be a fixed amount of lengths say around eight. Only the chain style (Curb) would have a different code. The widths have decimals 1mm 1.2 1.5 2mm 2.5 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using custom options; no custom coding is required. In your product, set the price under the Price tab to $10. Then, under custom options, setup your options like this:

[image: Customer Options]

This will increment the amount under 'Price' to your base price of $10.

This is how it looks on the frontend:

[image: frontend]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no requirement for per-width sku codes, you can use simple products and 'addition_options' to get the width and length to the backend.

You will need to include a custom box in your product template that gets the 'additional_options', you will also need some frontend javascript to update the price on the frontend so that it updates when the customer changes things.

Clearly the frontend javascript has to get the pricing from somewhere, you will have to work out how to do that (product attributes might work).

You can also use 'custom product options' (which will have a price part) but you will still need some frontend code.

On the backend have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15385689/3917602

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657041/get-a-value-of-a-custom-input-in-magento

Before you set out on your modifications you will need to think hard about your 'information architecture' and how the UX works.